# What are the shadow offset and color values to mimic the UINavigationBar Title?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am adding a UILabel as a titleView to a nav bar. I want the text to look like the title that display in the bar.

What are the offset and color to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it after playing around

Offset is default (0, -1)
Color is [UIColor darkGrayColor]

Comment: In case anyone stumbles across this, I think the font is Helvetica Bold 20.